# How do I convert a string with newlines characters into a string with YAML's folded style on file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, escaping, yaml, pyyaml

In many YAML files that I have, there usually exists this:

```
query: "SELECT\n  *\nFROM\n  (SELECT\n  'apple' AS fruit,\n  'carrot' AS vegetable);"
```

but I want to convert the above to instead appear like this:

```
query: >
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    "apple" AS fruit,
    "carrot" AS vegetable);
```

in the YAML file.

I just want the YAML to be more readable, and I want a way to convert the string without having to go into each YAML file that I have and change them by hand. I have tried printing the string above into stdout and redirecting that output into a variable, but that did not work for me.

The code of what I have tried doing:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import io

with io.StringIO() as buf, redirect_stdout(buf):
   print(query)
   yam['query'] = buf.getvalue()
```

But I just back the string with the escape characters.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  "did not work" is not a problem specification.  When I print the string you posted, I get something very close to your desired output.

Comment: @Prune I am confused by what you are asking for.

Comment: @martineau that just gives an array. I am not sure how to convert that into a multiline string.

Comment: If it has newlines in it, it's already a multiline string. `splitlines()` could convert that to a **`list`** of separate strings.

Comment: @martineau I decided to change the title to clarify what I am actually meant if it was unclear in the body of my question. I want the string with escape characters that appears in the yaml file to break over several lines in plain-text utf-8 encoding.

Comment: So what you want is an SQL prettyprinter. Take a look at `sqlparse`. https://pypi.org/project/sqlparse/

Comment: @BoarGules I am looking for a pretty print and `print()` works fine in printing the query in the way I want written on file, but I cannot find the way to write the pretty print to file. I have looked at `sqlparse`, and it's not quite what I want since it cannot seem to write to file without the escape characters in the sql string.

Answer (score 1):

Using a folded scalar is probably not what you want, because according
to the [spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2796251):

> Folding allows long lines to be broken anywhere a single space character separates two non-space characters.

And you have some lines broken between like that, but not all.

Additionally your output is not valid
YAML, you would need to indent the folded lines at least one
space. (The only time you don't have to indent a folded, or literal,
scalar is when it is the only node in a document.)

And lastly because you just use `>`, you'll have a newline at the end of the loaded value, i.e. after the semicolon, that is not there in the original.

---

I recommend you go for literal scalars where each newline is exactly a newline. If you file is in `input.yaml` the following will process any value lines that match the criteria you set:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

def try_convert(s):
    """return None if not converted"""
    if 'SELECT' not in s:
        return None
    if '\n' not in s:
        return None
    return ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.LiteralScalarString(s)

def recurse(d):
    """this walks recursively over the datastructure you loaded, entering elements of list, 
       and values of mappings
    """
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k in d:
            v = d[k]
            res = try_convert(v)
            if res is not None:
                d[k] = res
            else:
                recurse(d[k])
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for idx, elem in enumerate(d):
            res = try_convert(elem)
            if res is not None:
                d[idx] = res
            else:
                recurse(d)
    # nothing to do for scalars, which means a scalar in the root of a document will not be converted

file_name = Path('input.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(file_name)
recurse(data)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
query: |-
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    (SELECT
    'apple' AS fruit,
    'carrot' AS vegetable);
```

The strip chomping indicator (`-`) after the literal style indicator
(`|`) removes any number of newlines at the end of that scalar, so on
loading there will be no extra newline after the semi-colon.

You can of course call some SQL prettyprinter within convert. As long as its output is valid SQL and includes the newlines , you can pass it into `LiteralScalarString` and return it from `try_convert()`

Comment: To write to a file, instead of the screen, just pass the appropriate `Path()` instance, instead of `sys.stdout` to `.dump()` as second parameter.